# Understanding if regex validation in Jquery Validate

Tags: regex

I'm creating a new method and I'm trying to make sure I have my logic right and how I'm reading what I'm writing here.

```
$.validator.addMethod('checkDomain', function (value) { 

    if(/^([\w-.]+@(?!gmail\.com)(?!yahoo\.com)(?!hotmail\.com)(?!test\.com)([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test(value)) {
            return false;  // FAIL validation when REGEX matches    
            }
        else {
            return true;   // PASS validation otherwise
        }

}, 'Please provide a business email.');
```

What I'm trying to say here is if the email address matches gmail for example, set to false as we don't want that. Though when I set it to false it's backwards. Am I off on my regex? Will that return true if it matches one of the email domains?

Comment: You want all those negative lookaheads to be converted to positve ones inside of a single non-capturing group along with alterations.

Comment: Still learning. Coming from a limited knowledge base here with REGEX. Are you referring too ?! => ?=

Reference : https://regexr.com/   in the lookaround section.

Comment: Problem & solution 100% regex and jQuery Validate is only incidental.  Removed tag.

Answer (score 0):

The method [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) returns a boolean, you could shorten the if else to only a return statement.

Your regex is wrapped in an optional group `()?`, so an empty string will also match.

If you don't need the capturing group you could change this part `([\w-]+.)+` to `(?:[\w-]+\.)+` and escape the dot.

You could update your regex to:

```
^[\w-.]+@(?!(?:(?:hot|g)mail|yahoo|test)\.com)(?:[\w-]+\.)+\w{2,4}$
```

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DU75Rw/1)

For example, if the email address matches has any of gmail etc after the @ sign it will return true:

```
$.validator.addMethod('checkDomain', function (value) {
    return !/^[\w-.]+@(?!(?:(?:hot|g)mail|yahoo|test)\.com)(?:[\w-]+\.)+\w{2,4}$/.test(value);
}, 'Please provide a business email.');
```

```js
function checkDomain(value) {
  return !/^[\w-.]+@(?!(?:(?:hot|g)mail|yahoo|test)\.com)(?:[\w-]+\.)+\w{2,4}$/.test(value);
}

const strings = [
  "test@test.co",
  "test@test.com",
  "test@hotmail.com",
  "test@gmail.com"
];

strings.forEach(s => console.log(`${s}: ${checkDomain(s)}`));
```

Explanation

- `^` Start of string
- `[\w-.]+` Match 1+ times one of a word character, hyphen or dot
- `@` Match literally
- `(?!` Negative lookahead to check what follows is not

  - `(?:(?:hot|g)mail|yahoo|test)\.com` Non capturing group with an alternation
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `(?:[\w-]+\.)+` Repeat matching 1+ times one of a word character or hyphen followed by a dot
- `\.\w{2,4}` Match a dot and 2-4 word characters
- `$` End of string